# Routing issues in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am a beginner in MVC 4. I have an url **../Home/NameDetailsPage/20** where controller= **Home**, action=**NameDetailsPage** and pageIndex= **20**. How do i write my route engine for this url?

```
routes.MapRoute(
 ......
 .....
);
```

In controller, NameDetailsPage works pretty fine for default page such as int page=2 :-

```
 public ActionResult NameDetailsPage(int? page)
    {

        var context = new BlogContext();
        IQueryable<string> list;
        list = from m in context.Blogs.OrderBy(m => m.BlogId)
               select m.Name;

        ViewBag.total = list.ToArray().Length;
        ViewBag.page = page;

        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        ViewBag.page1 = pageNumber;

        return View("NameDetails", list.Skip(pageNumber * 4).Take(4));
    }
```

But the pageNumber is always 1 whatever pageIndex in the url. So It shows same result for all the pageIndex. How can I set pageNumber other than 1. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What routing have you tried? What did you see that was different to what you expected?

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Page",
                url: "Home/NameDetailsPage/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "NameDetailsPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a route like the following

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
);
```

The defaults object properties (controller, action, id) are what can be passed to the action (if the action has parameters that match the name).

So if you have an action:

```
public ActionResult NameDetailsPage(int? page)
```

there are no values being passed from the URL as `page`.

You can either change `{id}` to `{page}`, or preferably:

```
public ActionResult NameDetailsPage(int? id)
```

Comment: Yeah I gor it . Thanks a lot @erik

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you are most of the way there. You just need to define the parameter you are passing to the action. In this case switching {id} for {page} and altering the defaults to suit.

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    name: "Page", 
    url: "Home/NameDetailsPage/{page}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "NameDetailsPage", page = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Comment: Thanks brent  for your easy explanation. :)